# Not parsing all ini files in /etc/php.d

Tags: apache-httpd, php, selinux

Oracle Linux Server release 8.5
Apache/2.4.37 (Oracle Linux)
PHP 7.2.24

The specific INI file is `20-oci8.ini`, using `php -i` in the command line, it shows that the INI file was parsed and an OCI8 section, but via the web server it is not showing the INI file as being parsed and no OCI8 section.

I did write `20-oci8.ini` by scratch, so I thought it might be one of those SELinux permission issues, but nothing shows up in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

This appears to be a common problem, and I've done a lot of searching and tried a lot of things, including disabling SELinux, just for testing, but for sure not a permanent solution even if it did work.

Comment: Silly question, but did you restart the Apache web server after creating the `20-oci8.ini` file?

Comment: @John Yes, many times via `sudo apachectl restart`.

Comment: ls -alZ on /etc/php.d will show you if there's any permission, selinux, or ownership differences.

Comment: @MichaelKohne - it shows a different `_u`, `unconfined_u` vs `system_u`. Redid the INI file using `cp --preserve=context «existing-ini-file» 20-oci8.ini` then edited it. `ls -alZ` shows all good. Restarted Apache as above and also via `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`, but still not loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redid the INI file using `cp --preserve=context «existing-ini-file» 20-oci8.ini` then edited it.

`ls -alZ` shows all good.

Also server uses `php-fpm`, restarted explicitly using `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service`.

Restarted Apache using `sudo service apache2 restart`, now seeing OCI8!

Comment: +1 I had the exact same issue, but with a different ini file, restarting `php-fpm` was the key